# How to fix part of installation Path in VS Deployment project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am working on Visual Studio Deployment project in 2010. After I create a installation executable file, then while installing I want to fix some part of Path, that user cannot change it for example: My application name XYZABCD.exe

So When Installing it shows Path;

C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\XYZABCD\
//" XYZABCD contain my application file"

What I want is User can change this much path C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC.

but user cannot edit "XYZABCD" this path is fixed. How I can do that.

I am new with Visual Studio Deployment project, I am not getting how I can do?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this with Visual Studio setups. It's also a rather unusual requirement that I've not seen before.

In Visual Studio you'd need to create a custom action that checks the content of the TARGETDIR property to see if has the correct format, and then throw an install exception. This is a very unfriendly thing to do because custom actions in Visual Studio run after the file are all installed, so in other words the install fails right at the end and then rolls back. In different tools (such as WiX) you could write code that runs when the Next dialog is clicked - this code would check the format and prevent the dialogs from advancing if the format was wrong. However, preventing the dialogs from advancing in Visual Studio is not possible, so I'd recommend looking at whether this is an actual requirement or just a preference you have.